# where is the error in my code trying to compare case -insensitive using python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, case-insensitive

I have a code that read files and compare the content with a user-input with ignoring case-sensitive.

i used the list-comprehension in order to loop through the content and compare with user-input.

The problem is that the list comprehension return an empty list, although the entered word exist. Example:

## textContent

Les hiboux 
**Charl**es Baudelaire

Cycle 3 
*

POESIE

Sous les ifs noirs qui les abritent 
Les hiboux se tiennent rangés 
Ainsi que des dieux étrangers 
Dardant leur œil rouge. Ils méditent.

Sans remuer ils se tiendront 
Jusqu'à l'heure mélancolique 
Où, poussant le soleil oblique, 
Les ténèbres s'établiront.

Leur attitude au sage enseigne 
Qu'il faut en ce monde qu'il craigne 
Le tumulte et le mouvement ;

L'homme ivre d'une ombre qui passe 
Porte toujours le châtiment 
D'avoir voulu changer de place.

Les Fleurs du Mal 
1857

**Charl**es Pierre Baudelaire (1821 – 1867) est un poète français.

> user-input: charl
>   word exist : Charles--charle--CHARLE

```
x=self.lineEditSearch.text()
print(x)
textString=self.ReadingFileContent(Item)

#self.varStr =[c for c in textString if c.islower() or c.isupper() or c.capitalize()]            
self.varStr =[i for i in textString if i.lower() == x.lower()]            

print(self.varStr)
```

Comment: Try to make a minimal example that is executable but doesn't work. Like this, one cannot run your example because "self" is not defined.

Comment: None of the words "Charles", "charle" and "CHARLE" are equal to "charl", so an empty list is the correct output.

Comment: Do you mean to `zip(textString, x)`? This question is very confusing.

Comment: @Aran-Fey how is neither one is equal to charl ?--- what i expect is  to get a part of each word isn't that correct ?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq no there is no zip  i just  need to compare  user-input with text content

Comment: Please explain also what you mean by "compare".

Answer (score 0):

If

```
user_input = "charl"
word_exist = ["Charles","charle","CHARLE","Hello"]
```

Then

```
output = [item for item in word_exist if user_input.lower() in item.lower()]
print(output)
# ['Charles', 'charle', 'CHARLE']
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: YES  without using regular expression

Comment: This does not use regular expression

Comment: Please give a minimal example that can be run, like what your values for `x` and `textString`

Comment: that is what i did in the example that i give  where **x is  =  charl** and **textString =  textContent** i will edit my question and add the content of textString

Comment: `textString = "Charles--charle--CHARLE"` ? Like words separated by "--"?

Comment: textString =  to text  the separation parameter is **space**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you are only putting in `self.varStr` members of `textString` that satisfies `i.lower() == x.lower()`, which means "being completely the same (case insensitive) with `x`".

You want to pick up members that *contains* `x`.

You can do that by changing `i.lower() == x.lower()` into `i.lower() in x.lower()`